# How can I make query between dates in ElasticSearch?

Tags: performance, date, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to filter between two dates in ElasticSearch but I have the next error

This is the query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "message": "start_time"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "start_time": {
                            "gte": "09-02-2016",
                            "lte": "09-02-2016"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and the error

```
{
      "error": {
               "root_cause": [
              {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "failed to create query: For input string: \"09-02-2016\"",
                "index_uuid": "nLn_JFMDShW_PxAf7vgFyg",
                "index": "accidents"
              }
            ],
            "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
            "reason": "all shards failed",
            "phase": "query",
            "grouped": true,
            "failed_shards": [
              {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "accidents",
                "node": "x5unJW2PQsquLIpFsi9YQA",
                "reason": {
                  "type": "query_shard_exception",
                  "reason": "failed to create query: For input string: \"09-02-2016\"",
                  "index_uuid": "nLn_JFMDShW_PxAf7vgFyg",
                  "index": "accidents",
                  "caused_by": {
                    "type": "number_format_exception",
                    "reason": "For input string: \"09-02-2016\""
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "status": 400
        }
```

This is the field to filter

[image]

And It's an example that how start_time is saved

[image]

I had understood that ElasticSearch converts from date to number to have better performance but maybe it's wrong

I would like to be sure about if I am making the query well or why I've this problem

Comment: can you please post the actual code you are using and not a screenshot, it's very hard to read and replicate otherwise

Answer (score 1):

If you have configures the mapping correctly, you probably can use [the format option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#:%7E:text=or%20equal%20to.-,format,-(Optional%2C%20string)%20Date) to specify the date format.
So the query looks something like the one below.

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "message": "start_time"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "start_time": {
                            "gte": "09-02-2016",
                            "lte": "09-02-2016",
                            "format": "MM-dd-yyyy"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say you have an index like

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "start_date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_optional_time"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with data

```json
{"index": {}}
{"start_date": "2022-10-10"}
{"index": {}}
{"start_date": "2022-10-11"}
{"index": {}}
{"start_date": "2022-10-12"}
```

You can search the index with the query below.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "start_date": {
        "gte": "10-09-2022",
        "lte": "10-11-2022",
        "format": "MM-dd-yyyy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```